# Changing the size of the image in the sticky header when scrolling down

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, scroll

On the [website](https://miniskolka-adiscentrum.euweb.cz/krouzky/) (please don't share), in WordPress, I set a sticky header using CSS

```
header#masthead {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 10000;
}
```

This works correctly. However, the image in the header is too big, that's why I resized it with an animation when scrolling down

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    jQuery(function() {

        var $nav = jQuery('#masthead .custom-logo');
        var height_original = jQuery('#masthead .custom-logo').css("height").replace("px","");
        var height_small = height_original * 0.666;
        var width_original = jQuery('#masthead .custom-logo').css("width").replace("px","");    
        var width_small = width_original * 0.666;

        jQuery(document).scroll( function() {

            var value = jQuery(this).scrollTop();

            if ( value > 0 ){
                $nav.stop().animate({height:height_small,width:width_small},100);
            } else if (value == 0 ) {
                $nav.stop().animate({height:height_original,width:width_original},100);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

But, it doesn't work properly.

I primarily use Opera GX, where it behaves like this - when scrolling down, the animation is slowed down. Also, if you just scroll down a little, the animation doesn't run all the way and the image goes back to its original size, scrolling up works without a problem.

The strange thing is that I've also tried it in Firefox, Chrome and Edge. It behaves differently in everyone, but nowhere does it work 100% correctly.

What is wrong with the code please?

Thank you

Comment: What is the actual goal, what should the animation do?  I think one problem is that you are resizing to the same size, every time, bcs you are re-using the initial CSS width/height in your `*_small` values.  If the logo is say 100x100 initially, when you scroll 1 pixel down it will resize to 66x66.  When you scroll another 1px, to 2px total down, it will again resize to 66x66.  Should it actually be getting smaller?  In which case you want to use the *current* size as the starting point, and multiply that by .66?

Comment: The typical way to do this is to define your target small size in CSS, eg `.small { width: 66px;}`, then add that class when you reach some scroll point, and use a transition to animate between them.  [Here's a simple example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46172834/resizing-logo-when-scrolling).  Would that work for you?

Comment: I apologize for the delayed response. Thanks, but I didn't understand exactly how to modify my code. Could you write me an example, please?

Answer (score 0):

I think instead of that long jquery code you can use this simple javascript code with some css to get the results you want:
I hope this helps you to reach what you looking for :)

**JS**

```
// Add a class to the header when scrolling
let header = document.querySelector('header'); 
window.addEventListener('scroll' , function () {
    let window_top = this.scrollY;
    if (window_top == 0) {
        header.classList.remove('resize');
    }else {
        header.classList.add('resize'); 
    }
});
```

**CSS**

```
/* these are the default styles (when the user doesnt scroll down yet) */
header#masthead {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 10000;
    transition: .3s;
}
header#masthead img{
    transition: .3s; /*here i added transition to give the image a smooth animation*/
}
/* these are the styles when the user scrolls */
header#masthead.resize img{
    height: 50px; /* <=== here i gived the image a smaller size */
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately it works even worse than before. The image doesn't change immediately when scrolling down, but only from a certain position. And most importantly, this isn't an animation, the image suddenly turns into an unsightly "noodle". Unfortunately it does this in all 4 browsers mentioned. And I've tried disabling all plugins (except the one to add HTML/CSS/JS code) and it didn't help, so obviously no plugin has an effect on the bad functionality. I really don't know what to think about it.

Comment: I updated the code, in CSS i gave the image transition to 0.3 seconds ((you can change it to more or less, that depends on how you want the animation duration)) so it will have smooth animation on scrolling, and I updated the Javascript code so it will change immediately on scrolling, try it now and tell me if it works better :)

Comment: Thanks for the effort, now it happens immediately on scroll down, but unfortunately still no animation and bad aspect ratio. It works "best" in Firefox, where the image changes immediately when you scroll down. In Chrome, Edge and Opera GX, the image change "flickers" and I have to turn the mouse wheel several times to even get down. However, when fully scrolled up, the image changes to its original size and there is no "flickering" in any browser.